# How can I remove ?v=2222dddhh4 from img srouce in shopify?

Tags: shopify

How can I remove ?v=2222dddhh4 from img srouce in shopify ?

Main source:
    [image]

I want:

```
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1608/4177/files/Size_Guide.png>
```

Comment: I would advise against this. Even though removing the version will allow the image to be cached, it also could prevent your users from seeing the most up-to-date image if you change it. Shopify uses multiple servers that store images and the version number helps pull in the most up-to-date image if say you recently uploaded a new image with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using javacsript and jquery maybe help you:

```
$('img').each(function(){
 var _src = $(this).attr('src');//get attribute src
 _src = _src.replace(/\?v=.*?$/g,'');
 $(this).attr('src',_src);//replace your same img
 $('span').append(_src);//for test
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/vuLtcjwb)

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply use:
`| split:'?' | first`
it will split your link from '?' and will show just the first part which is the link before the '?'.